# Java Sockets not connecting to most sites

Tags: java, sockets, ports, network-scan

I am writing a program that simply tests connections to ports on remote machines and checks if a connection was established or rejected, pretty much a port scanner. While it seems to work on localhost and some sites, for some reason it won't work on most IP addresses, when several of my classmates followed similar approaches and were able to probe these same sites. Some sites, such as wikipedia.org, will only go up to port 21 and then hang. Can anyone see any obvious problems with my code. Thansk in advance.

```
for(int i = 1; i <= maxPort; i++)
    {
            boolean found = true;
            try
            {
                    String[] hostNameArray = hostName.split(".");
                    socket = new Socket(hostName, i);
                    System.out.println("Test");


                    socket.close();
            }
            catch(java.net.ConnectException ex)
            {
                    System.out.println("Error" + ex + "\t<"+i+">");
                    found = false;
            }
            catch(java.net.UnknownHostException ex)
            {
                    System.out.println("Unknown host");
                    System.exit(-1);
            }
            catch(IOException ex)
            {
                    System.out.println("IO Exception");
                    System.exit(-2);
            }
            if(found)
            {
                    ports.add(i);
            }
    }
```

Places such as google.com will simply stop when I try to create the socket (i.e. the test statement is never printed) while wikipedia.org will simply hang after 21. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: And just for the sake of it: you understand that extensive port scanning is an activity that might get you in trouble? Some people/countries/authorities even think it is a crime ...

Comment: Well-maintained web servers are even more wary of port scanning than the average network-connected machine.  And port scanning without permission is not *nice*.  In some places it may be illegal.  Moreover, firewalls can drop connection requests to blocked ports instead of denying them, which is in part an intentional defense against port scanning, as it causes the scanner to wait a long time for a response that will never come.

Comment: I don't see anything inherently wrong with your code, though you should allow several minutes (maybe tens of minutes) per port scanned before you declare it to have hung.  You should consider whether your classmates' code that does not hang is in fact scanning the same ports of the same machines at all.  Maybe it's their code that is broken, not yours.